# A persistence error occurred in JSF application

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

I'm getting a persistence error when trying to submit a form in a jsf application. I'm using a glassfish server and a mysql database. When i try to add to the database i keep getting the error.

here is the code from the jsf page

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <h:body>
                   <--code omitted for clarity--->

                <div id="cdscreatecontrol">
                <div align="center"><h:commandButton action="#{cdsController.create}" immediate="true" value="#{bundle.CreateCdsSaveLink}"/></div>
                <br /><div align="center"><h:commandButton action="#{cdsController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateCdsShowAllLink}" immediate="true"/></div>
                <br /><div align="center"><h:link outcome="/index" value="Back to Login Page"/></div></div>  

            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
                    </div>

            <div id="footer" style="margin-top: 1100px"><div style="margin-top: 10px">
                    Copyright © David McGuinness IT Development DPD Athlone</div>
                <div id="button">
                    <h:form><h:commandButton  action="/mainmenu.xhtml"
                       image="menu.png" style="height: 20px; width: 90px; float: left; 
                         margin-left: 15px;" onmouseover="this.src = 'menupress.png'" 
                         onmouseout="this.src = 'menu.png'"></h:commandButton></h:form>
                    <h:form><h:commandButton onclick="window.opener=null;window.open('','_self');window.close();" 
                       image="exit.png" style="height: 20px; width: 90px; float: right; 
                         margin-right: 15px;" onmouseover="this.src = 'exitpress.png'" 
                         onmouseout="this.src = 'exit.png'"></h:commandButton></h:form>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </h:body>

</html>
```

here the code form the java file

```
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package jpa.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author david.mcguinness
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "cds")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findByDatecreated", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE c.datecreated = :datecreated"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findByDpdaccountno", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE c.dpdaccountno = :dpdaccountno"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findByCustname", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE c.custname = :custname"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findByExistingcust", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE c.existingcust = :existingcust"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findByDepot", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE c.depot = :depot"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findByItcontact", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE c.itcontact = :itcontact"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findByConspernight", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE   c.conspernight = :conspernight"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findByDomestic", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE c.domestic = :domestic"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findByUk", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE c.uk = :uk"),

@Column(name = "datecreated" )
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date datecreated;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 225)
@Column(name = "dpdaccountno")
private String dpdaccountno;
@Size(max = 225)
@Column(name = "custname")
private String custname;
@Size(max = 4)
@Column(name = "existingcust")
private String existingcust;
@Size(max = 225)
@Column(name = "depot")
private String depot;
@Size(max = 225)
@Column(name = "itcontact")
private String itcontact;
@Column(name = "conspernight")
private Integer conspernight;
@Size(max = 4)
@Column(name = "domestic")
private String domestic;
@Size(max = 4)
@Column(name = "uk")
private String uk;


public Cds() {
}

public Cds(String dpdaccountno) {
    this.dpdaccountno = dpdaccountno;
}

public Date getDatecreated() {
    return datecreated;
}

public void setDatecreated(Date datecreated) {
    this.datecreated = datecreated;
}

public String getDpdaccountno() {
    return dpdaccountno;
}

public void setDpdaccountno(String dpdaccountno) {
    this.dpdaccountno = dpdaccountno;
}

public String getCustname() {
    return custname;
}

public void setCustname(String custname) {
    this.custname = custname;
}

public String getExistingcust() {
    return existingcust;
}

public void setExistingcust(String existingcust) {
    this.existingcust = existingcust;
}

public String getDepot() {
    return depot;
}

public void setDepot(String depot) {
    this.depot = depot;
}

public String getItcontact() {
    return itcontact;
}

public void setItcontact(String itcontact) {
    this.itcontact = itcontact;
}

public Integer getConspernight() {
    return conspernight;
}

public void setConspernight(Integer conspernight) {
    this.conspernight = conspernight;
}

public String getDomestic() {
    return domestic;
}

public void setDomestic(String domestic) {
    this.domestic = domestic;
}

public String getUk() {
    return uk;
}

public void setUk(String uk) {
    this.uk = uk;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (dpdaccountno != null ? dpdaccountno.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Cds)) {
        return false;
    }
    Cds other = (Cds) object;
    if ((this.dpdaccountno == null && other.dpdaccountno != null) || (this.dpdaccountno   != null && !this.dpdaccountno.equals(other.dpdaccountno))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "jpa.entities.Cds[ dpdaccountno=" + dpdaccountno + " ]";
}

}
```

here is the code from the abstractFacade Class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package jpa.session;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

/**
 *
 * @author david.mcguinness
 */
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

here is the entire stack trace

```
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy237.create(Unknown Source)
at jpa.session.__EJB31_Generated__CdsFacade__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
at jsf.CdsController.create(CdsController.java:84)
at jsf.CdsController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.create(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s)         violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please     refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:90)
at   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(Be     anValidationListener.java:62)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:748)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:691)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:229)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4310)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4287)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:518)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4229)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
at jpa.session.AbstractFacade.create(AbstractFacade.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor130.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
... 50 more
```

Comment: What does the error/excpetion say ?

Comment: all i get is "A persistence error occurred." Omar

Comment: this error is in the logs

Comment: WARNING:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB CdsFacade, method: public void jpa.session.AbstractFacade.create(java.lang.Object)

Comment: This is only part of the exception trace. Edit the question and add the entire stack trace formatted as a code block.

Comment: Also note that the question in not in format of a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You should for example reduce the fields of the entity to the minimum set of fields that are necessary to reproduce the error, delete obvious things like getters/setters. And add cdsController that is missing but seems to be the class where the error is originated.

Comment: i hope thats better perissf

Answer (score 1):

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findByNorthernirelandb", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE           @NamedQuery(name = "Cds.findBySwapit", query = "SELECT c FROM Cds c WHERE c.swapit =   :swapit"),
```

Of course, with such a mistake, you will get a compilation error (of the persistence layer). Can you spot your mistake ?

**Edit :**

OK, as you have re-edited your question and as the problem is not coming from the above named query, I can now tell you that you are most probably forgetting to set the id of the entity while trying to persist it, or that one or some of the entries do not respect fixed constraints.

Try to commit the transaction in a try catch block of statements (catch with `ConstraintViolationException`).

To know the constraint violations before the commit , you can insert this block of code

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

Set<ConstraintViolation<Cds>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(theObjectInQuestion);

if (constraintViolations.size() > 0 ) {
System.out.println("Constraint Violations occurred..");
for (ConstraintViolation<Cds> contraints : constraintViolations) {
System.out.println(contraints.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName()+
"." + contraints.getPropertyPath() + " " + contraints.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a mistake i made when i was trying to formnat the code properly here.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in the exception log, the method at `jsf.CdsController.create(CdsController.java:84)` is trying to create an entity of type `Cds` that doesn't pass the validation constraints:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) 
violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'
```

Since you haven't yet posted the way you have initialized the entity, and since the exception is not telling anything about which property is failing the validation, it's hard to tell more, but you can debug in many ways, like:

- by removing one by one all the properties and changing the db table structure accordingly, until the exception goes away
- by removing one by one the `@NotNull` and `@Size` constraints until the exception goes away (be careful, if the db table structure is not updated accordingly, you might have db errors)
- as suggested in the comment by SujanSivagurunathan, by catching the `ConstraintViolationException` in order to get more infos about the exception itself.

#### See also:

- [The Java EE 7 Tutorial: Using Bean Validation Constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/bean-validation001.htm#GIRCZ)

Comment: Best way to debug is to catch the `ConstraintViolationException`. Removing `@NotNull` will only increase problems IF the Data structure is not also changed in the DB (MySQL in this case).